# Cooling GPU in a rig

Tags: mining-hardware, miner-configuration

I don't know if this is the correct forum for asking this kind question please let me know. Anyway, I have a small rig with two GPUs (SAPPHIRE Pulse Radeon RX 580 8G GDDR5 Dual HDMI/DVI-D/Dual DP Graphics Card), the GPU temperature is running at 74℃, the inboard fans are running in AUTO at 20%, I have two external fans that I would like to use to cool it. 
My question is where should I position the fans? in front, back, below or uppers side  of the GPU? The back side where the name of the GPU is, is the hottest part of the device, I am afraid to set the external fans in an incorrect position and make the inboard fans workload. Any help is more than welcome.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use msi afterburner, set your gpu fans to 80% and TDP 70% then play around with core clock and memory clock, maybe +100/+450 is a good place to start

this will give you better cooling, lower power costs and better hash rates

Comment: Thanks for the info in the beginning is difficult to get help.